# Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'ItemTotal'

Tags: sql, sql-server, column-alias

I wrote this code. It works fine without my WHERE Statement. I keep getting an error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'ItemTotal'.

I don't know what I did wrong!

```
SELECT    
    ItemID, 
    ItemPrice,    
    ItemPrice * quantity AS PriceTotal,
    DiscountAmount * quantity AS DiscountTotal,
    ((ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) * quantity) AS ItemTotal
FROM                                                                                                                                                               
    OrderItems
WHERE ItemTotal > 500;
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the database system you are using

Comment: You can't filter on a alias!

Comment: I am not! I will start doing this. Very new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No database platform was given, but based on the query: 'ItemTotal' is not a column you can use, as it's an alias. You need to filter on the actual data

```
SELECT    
    ItemID, 
    ItemPrice,    
    ItemPrice * quantity AS PriceTotal,
    DiscountAmount * quantity AS DiscountTotal,
    ((ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) * quantity) AS ItemTotal
FROM                                                                                                                                                               
    OrderItems
WHERE ((ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) * quantity) > 500;
```